# Load CSV files in script when script ran outside of directory

Tags: python

I am having an issue of trying to load CSV files in a python script when trying to run the file from outside the directory of the script called `main.py` and the CSV files. (CSV files and main are in the same directory) I think the [same issues as this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65334371/executing-python-script-in-terminal-when-outside-of-scripts-directory) which doesn't appear to contain a solution.

If I run this from terminal:

`$ python /home/bbartling/Desktop/Load-Shredder/Load-Shift/main.py`

I get some CSV file loading errors `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'addresses_jci.csv'`

But if I run the script in the directory of Load-Shift `$ python main.py` it works just fine.

How do I fix my script to accommodate this? I added this to the top of my script:

```
script_dir = os.path.abspath( os.path.dirname( __file__ ) )
print("script directory: ",script_dir)
```

which prints:

```
script directory:  /home/bbartling/Desktop/Load-Shredder/Load-Shift
```

But still no luck. Any ideas to try?

**Edit**

CSV file loading function in main.py

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(dir_path, f'log_{dt_string}.log')
script_dir = os.path.abspath( os.path.dirname( __file__ ) )
print("script directory: ",script_dir)

def load_addresses(csv_file):
    try:
        print(f"Loading csv file: {csv_file}!")
        os.path.join(script_dir, f'{csv_file}.csv')
        with open(f'{csv_file}', newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            data = list(reader)

        # flattens list of lists
        csv_file = sum(data, [])
        print(f"{csv_file} addresses loaded: ",csv_file)

    except Exception as error:
        print(f"CSV file load error: {error}")
        csv_file = [] # errors out

    return csv_file
```

Comment: A path like `addresses_jci.csv` will be interpreted relative to `os.getcwd()`, which is the directory you run your command from: that's why you see the behaviour you do.  You could do something like `os.path.join(script_dir, 'addresses_jci.csv')` to find an absolute path to the file, and use that when opening the file.

Comment: In the `main.py` script, can you just add the full path directly to the csv file?

Comment: I added an EDIT to the post with the `os.path.join(script_dir, f'{csv_file}.csv')` in the `try` @slothrop but still same issue. Maybe I should just try hard coding the full path of the file? Any tips appreciated

Comment: @bbartling It should be something like `with open(os.path.join(script_dir, f'{csv_file}.csv')) as f:`

Comment: Try any of this `rf"{os.path.dirname(__file__)}/FILE.csv"`  or safe and best practice `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "FILE.csv")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code, I think you did not update the csv_file variable update:

`csv_file = os.path.join(script_dir, f'{csv_file}.csv')`

Though it can be more simpler:

```py
import os

script_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = 'sample'

file_path = os.path.join(script_path, f'{filename}.csv')
print(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

filepaths in general are a bit confusing in programming languages, so this is a very common problem for beginners.

I typically have a fixed working directory for my projects, and tend to access all files relative to that working directory. If you can implement it, this is the simplest solution.

```
$ cd /home/bbartling/Desktop/Load-Shredder/Load-Shift/
$ python main.py
```

can give the desired solution, but depending upon your project this may or may not be feasible. This is by no means a hard-code or a hot fix, and perfectly valid for my projects. However, if you're making a reusable shell script, you probably don't want this.

I've used `Path(__file__).parent` before to get the directory the file is running in, but IDK how the speed compares to the way you compute it.

I've used this a couple times before V

```py
import os
HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
with open(os.path.join(HERE, 'mkdocs.yml')) as fl:
    print(fl.read())
```

You can change the filename here to your script's path, and that will work. If you know where it will be stored relative to your `main.py` dir, you can hard-code it. otherwise get it from the command line or console, whichever you prefer. Use the relative path from your main.py directory to your csv here.

Answer (score 0):

This is working! in the function to load a file:

THIS WORKS with specifing object to reference for the os.path.join:

`full_csv_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f'{csv_file}')`

THIS DOESNT WORK without specifying an object for the program to reference:

`os.path.join(dir_path, f'{csv_file}')`

Example below that also includes logging:

```
import csv, os, logging


# datetime object containing current date and time
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%m_%d_%Y %H_%M_%S")
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(dir_path, f'log_{dt_string}.log')

# Logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

print("dir_path is: ",dir_path)

def load_addresses(csv_file):
    try:
        print(f"Loading csv file: {csv_file}!")
        full_csv_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f'{csv_file}')
        print("full_csv_path: ",full_csv_path)
        with open(full_csv_path, newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            data = list(reader)

        # flattens list of lists
        csv_file = sum(data, [])
        print(f"{csv_file} addresses loaded: ",csv_file)

    except Exception as error:
        print(f"CSV file load error: {error}")
        csv_file = [] # errors out

    return csv_file
```

Comment: this shouldn't be happening. can you tell the example and counterexample to prove your point?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` , `os` and `fnmatch` for this purpose as given below,

```
import pandas as pd
import os,fnmatch

# change path to the folder from another folder
os.chdir("/path_to_the_folder_having_files_from_another_folder")

# print the current working directory to check if you have arrived
# in the right folder/directory

print(os.getcwd())


# then use fnmatch package to get the CSV files only
# or you can make some other pattern using some prefix or suffix
# like *this.csv or *that.csv

files = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('.'), '*.csv')

# print the files to check that you have captured the right files

files

# read your files using pandas
# be careful with `sep`, you need to check specifically for your 
# files 

csv_files = [pd.read_csv(f, low_memory=False,sep = "\t",header=0 for f in files]
```